# How to pulse DS28E04 with owserver?

Tags: 1-wire

I want to pulse a LED using parasitic power on a ow network using [owserver](http://owfs.org/index.php?page=ds2804).

If you send the correct command the pin will pulse for between 250 ms and 1000 ms.  The [datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS28E04-100.pdf) pulse access example sequence is `CCh A5h FEh 01h` to pulse P0.

Using i = C dv/dt with 1 V and 1 mA and 1 s C = 1000 uF so fairly realistic.

How do you send this command with owserver?

The alternative might be to use a smaller capacitor and drain the passive DS28E04 supply pin until it resets.  Will this work?

Answer (score 1):

Following this up with `owfs-developers` I discovered that the function is not currently implemented.

Watch this space...

Comment: I'm watching! :-) I've just asked a very slightly [related question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/76262/35753).

Comment: This is a very specific hardware implementation issue.  owfs works well!